# System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: soap, anonymous, svcutil.exe, basichttpbinding

I've been trying to consume a WCF service outside my company. On my local machine environment it works just fine. On my cluster (Linux env), however, I got the message "**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'**."

My Reference class was created by **svcutil**. This is a peace of the code responsable for the httpBinding:

```
            BasicHttpBinding result = new BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;

            return result;
```

I've struggled with this for so long and would appreciate any clue on the issue.

I've tried to setup my class like this:

```
            BasicHttpBinding result = new BasicHttpBinding();
            result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            result.AllowCookies = true;
            result.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            result.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

            return result;
```

Still, I got the error message mentioned... The service I've been trying to call runs on HTTP. Could anybody help me out?